# Producing a Java-formated matrix in MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab, matrix

I have a code in MATLAB that gives me a matrix at the end. I need to take this matrix to Java and use it there, but when the matrix is big, it is really hard to rewrite it element by element in Java. So I wrote this code in MATLAB:

```
function JavaMatrix = generateJavaFormatedMatrix(matrix, name) 
    for i=1:size(matrix,1)
        for j=1:size(matrix,2)
            JavaMatrix(i,j) = char([name '[' num2str(i-1) ']' '[' num2str(j-1) ']=' num2str(matrix(i,j)) ';' ' '])
        end
    end
end
```

Which I expect it to do the trick for me, and then I just need to copy the array and paste it in Java. For example, what I want the above code to do when I write the following command:

```
java_matrix = generateJavaFormatedMatrix(eye(3),'A')
```

is the following

```
A[0][0]=1; A[0][1]=0; A[0][2]=0;
A[1][0]=0; A[1][1]=1; A[1][2]=0;
A[2][0]=0; A[2][1]=0; A[2][2]=1;
```

However, what I am getting is the following error:

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in generateJavaFormatedMatrix (line 5)
            JavaMatrix(i,j) = char([name '[' num2str(i-1) ']' '[' num2str(j-1) ']=' num2str(matrix(i,j)) ';' ' '])
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `JavaMatrix(i,j)` is only one element (character). You're assigning a whole string to it.

Comment: Why is this approach desired over just exporting to an intermediate file? Or importing it in java directly?

Comment: @beaker, why isn't it possible to assign a string as an array element?

Comment: @excaza, because my Java code code will end up by running on an Android device, and I don't want each time to update the text file to send it to the phone.

Comment: Try this: `S = 'Hello, World!"`. Now look at the size of `S`. 13 characters will not fit in the space of one character.

Comment: I don't understand how this prevents having to send something to the phone.

Comment: @M.A. The alternative to using an intermediate file is hard-coding the array in your Java code... am I missing something? It doesn't sound like something you want to do...

Comment: @Dev-iL, I am fine with hard-coding the array in Java code since it won't change after words, I will keep on using it over and over as long as the app is running.

Comment: @M.A. Which version of MATLAB are you using? The latest version (R2016b) has a new [`string`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html) datatype which you could use the way you wanted in the question. Alternatively, assign the character vectors into a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html).

Comment: @Dev-iL, I am using MATLAB version R2012a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code that does the trick.

```
function s = generateJavaFormatedMatrix( A, sigdigs, name )
if nargin < 2
    sigdigs = 15;
end
format  = [ '%+1.', int2str(sigdigs), 'e' ]; 
s       = sprintf( 'final double [][] %s = {\n', name ); 
for row = 1:size(A,1)
    s   = [ s, '    { ' ];
    for col = 1:size(A,2)
        s   = [ s, num2str( A(row,col), format ) ];
        if ( col ~= size(A,2) )
            s   = [ s, ', ' ];
        end
    end
    if row == size(A,1)
        s   = sprintf( [ s, ' } \n' ] );
    else 
        s   = sprintf( [ s, ' }, \n' ] );
    end
end
s   = [ s, '};' ];
```

So for example, running this command

```
>> generateJavaFormatedMatrix( eye(3), 3, 'A' ):
```

will give:

```
ans =

final double [][] A = {
    { +1.000e+00, +0.000e+00, +0.000e+00 }, 
    { +0.000e+00, +1.000e+00, +0.000e+00 }, 
    { +0.000e+00, +0.000e+00, +1.000e+00 } 
};
```